# Convert datetime and timedelta from Python to IDL

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, idl-programming-language

Please does anyone know how to convert the following python script to IDL,

```
hours = list(Timed)
start_date = datetime(year=1800, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
days =[] 
Months =[]
Years =[]   
for hour in hours:
    date = start_date + timedelta(hours=hour)
    Months.append(date.month)
    Years.append(date.year)
```

The script converts the data below to day, month, and year starting from 1800:00:00.0

```
Timed = [1.52887e+06,1.52959e+06,1.53034e+06,1.53108e+06,1.5318e+06,1.53254e+06,1.53326e+06,1.53401e+06,1.53475e+06,1.53542e+06,1.53617e+06,1.53689e+06,1.53763e+06]
```

I want to rewrite the Python script in IDL.

Comment: Interactive Data Language (IDL)

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [CALDAT](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/caldat.html) and [JULDAY](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/julday.html).
You need to convert `Timed` to days.

```
IDL> start_date = julday(1, 1, 1800, 0, 0, 0)
IDL> Timed = [1.52887e+06,1.52959e+06,1.53034e+06,1.53108e+06,1.5318e+06,1.53254e+06,1.53326e+06,1.53401e+06,1.53475e+06,1.53542e+06,1.53617e+06,1.53689e+06,1.53763e+06]
IDL> caldat, start_date + (Timed / 24), month, day, year  ; convert Timed to days and add to start_date
IDL> year                                               
        1974        1974        1974        1974        1974        1974        1974        1975        1975        1975        1975
        1975        1975
IDL> month
           5           6           8           9          10          10          11           1           1           2           4
           5           5
IDL> day
          31          30           1           1           1          31          30           1          31          28           1
           1          31
```

Comment: Nice!!
I just wanted to post the way I solved it.


        `Timediff = (Timed - 1490181)*3600
         for t = 0L, N_ELEMENTS(Timediff)-1 do begin    
         Time_Datax = SYSTIME(ELAPSED=Timediff(t))
         BinTime = BIN_DATE(Time_Datax)
         Yeartime= BinTime[0]
         Monthtime = BinTime[1]
         daytime = BinTime[2]
         endfor `

Thanks

Comment: @TThoye You can [add yours as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then accept the one that you think is best. The main advantages of the one I posted are probably speed (no `for` loop) and fewer "magic numbers".

Comment: You are right. Your answer is more excellent. I never thought that way. Thanks